# Receiving frame from udp is too slow for face recognition

Tags: c++, c, opencv, deep-learning, udp

I want to receive frames from UDP port and run face recognition algorithms on them with opencv cv::dnn framework. **Tello** drone is sending frames over UDP protocol.

```
/* load dnn model */
    cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe("dnnmodel/deploy.prototxt.txt","dnnmodel/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel");
    cv::VideoCapture cap("udp://@0.0.0.0:11111?overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000");
    cv::Mat frame;

    float confidenceThreshold = 0.2;
   
    while(true)
    {   
        if(!cap.read(frame))
            break;

        cv::Mat inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, 1, cv::Size(300, 300), cv::Scalar(104.0, 177.0, 123.0), false, false);
        net.setInput(inputBlob, "data");
        cv::Mat detection = net.forward("detection_out");
        cv::Mat detectionMat(detection.size[2], detection.size[3], CV_32F, detection.ptr<float>());

        
        cv::imshow("window", frame);

        char key = cv::waitKey(10);
        if (key == 27) // ESC
            break;
    }
```

Camera response time is very high like 10-20 seconds. When I move the camera, I get the new frame after 20 seconds.

But If I used my own laptop webcam instead of udp port in VideoCapture with this call ;

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0)
```

result is perfect. There is no delay when I am using the webcam.

What is the reason of this delay ?

Comment: My guess is that the data rate from the drone is really slow, and the video frames are really big. To calculate the expected time, divide the video frame size (in bits) by the data rate (in bits/sec).

Comment: @user3386109 If it is, what can i do ?

Comment: To decrease the frame size, either increase the video compression, or reduce the video resolution (both of which reduce image quality).  The other option is to increase the data rate. But that's assuming that frame size / data rate *is* the problem. Step one is to figure out the frame size and data rate, and verify that the actual frame transmission time is close to the calculated frame transmission time. If the expected time is 1 sec, and you're measuring 20 seconds, then something else is going on.

Comment: @user3386109 But if i do not do face recognition, there is no delay.

Comment: Well, the face recognition takes a lot of time?  Thread off the face recognition?

Comment: @MartinJames If I use my webcam, face recognition works perfectly, but If i use face recognition with UPD read, response time is too slow. I was thinking about threading the face recognition but, why webcam works properly ?

Comment: If you open the stream in something like VLC, do you also see the delay?

Comment: OK, large pool of buffers and a seperate thread for the UDP, pushing buffer pointers onto a P-C queue as soon as they are received instead of waiting for face-recog latency?

Comment: The webcam probably generates a steadier stream of buffers?  Guessing now, you sbould investigate further to identify the delay mechanism.  More logging:)

Comment: @MartinJames Can you check that am i wrong ? You say that, as soon as new frame readed by the UDP handler thread, push this frame into the queue, and continue to showing frame by imshow and accept new frames. Other side, face recog thread do processing and change the current frame object that is on the screen ?

Comment: Well, your overall design is up to you.  I do sense that it is very important to have a thread ready to receive datagrams as soon as available and queue them off, else they may be discarded by the comms stack:(

Comment: @user253751 I used ffmpeg, there is no delay. With using webcam and face recog = no delay, with using udp and face recog = huge delay, with using udp and no face recog = no delay.

Comment: Yeah - get the UDP receive threaded off, get those datagrams out of the comms stack independently of the facial recog:)

Comment: @MartinJames I cannot understand one point. When using face recognition on port, video is not freezing,FPS is good, it is fluent. But stream is delayed. I think I was misunderstood. I comment the face recongnition code and add usleep(500000) in order to simulate the face recognition, now it is freezing, not delaying.

Comment: @MartinJames It works ! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With unreliable protocols like UDP, where the comms stack can, and will, discard data if not promptly taken out to user space, it's important to attach a high importance to reading data, even at the expense of added complexity in the recv code.

In this case, a separate thread can be used to extract datagrams as soon as available and queueing the buffers, (pointers to buffers, anyway), off to processing code that, otherwise, would result in excessive time use and dropped datagrams.

Hey - it worked!

Comment: In addition to Martin’s answer, I used P-C queue. Udp thread reads frame and immediately push this frame into queue. Face recog thread pops frames from queue, process them and show to the screen. By this way, UDP datagrams retrieved without waiting processing the frame. If anyone faces with this problem, this may help.

Comment: but I am wondering one point. Face recog thread pop frames from the queue and process them. It can show the mew frame after the processing. So it is waiting the processing the frame. But there is no delay. I can not under stand it %100. Is it related about your first paragraph ? Are UDP datagrams must be caught as soon as possible ?